# How can you add Rich Pins Meta Tags for Bigcommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

I'd like to enable my Bigcommerce website for Rich Pins in Pinterest. What are the appropriate meta tags to do this?

Comment: Sorry, I want to mark it as answer. Couldn't find it anywhere to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The above is incorrect, it should actually be as follows:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />  
<meta property="og:price:amount" content="%%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%%" />
<meta property="og:price:currency" content="USD" />
<meta property="og:availability" content="in stock"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are the rich pins meta tags that you can put it in your Bigcommerce template
File. **product.html**
just after %%Panel.HTMLHead%%

```
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />  
<meta property="product:price:amount" content="%%GLOBAL_RetailPrice%%"/>  
<meta property="product:price:currency" content="AUD" /> 
<meta property="og:availability" content="in stock"/>
```

All others tags are already provided from BigCommerce Template
in HTMLhead.html file
 %%GLOBAL_AdditionalMetaTags%%

But if something is missing here is the full list you can use in addition to above.

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="YOURSITE.COM" /> 
<meta property="og:title" content="%%GLOBAL_ProductName%%" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="%%PageContent%%" />
<meta itemprop="description" content="%%ProductDescription%%" />  
<meta property="og:image" content="%%GLOBAL_ThumbImageURL%%"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, neither will work if you load additional products on your page, for example with "Related" or "Recently Viewed" blocks as it will load the last product on the page as the product price.

Instead you can use the Schema.org Semantic Markup option instead.

The following code at the bottom of my productdetails.html page passed the Pinterest validator.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<meta itemprop="name" content="%%GLOBAL_ProductName%%" />
<meta itemprop="image" content="%%GLOBAL_ThumbImageURL%%" />
<meta itemprop="description" content="%%Page.MetaDescription%%">
    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <meta itemprop="price" content="%%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%%">
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
    <meta itemprop="availability" itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemAvailability" content="http://schema.org/InStock" />
    </div>
</div>
```